# How to wsprintf const char*

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print the value of `translatedMessage` but its printing `?????`

```
static std::map<int, const char*> wmTranslation = {
    {0, "WM_NULL" },
    {1, "WM_CREATE" },
    {2, "WM_DESTROY" },
    //....

};

void Msg(int Msg) {
    const char* translatedMessage = wmTranslation[Msg];
    WCHAR wsText[255] = L"";
    wsprintf(wsText, L"Msg: %s", translatedMessage);
    OutputDebugString(wsText);
}
```

What would be the correct way to print it?

Comment: read the docs. that’s probably %S (*capital* S)

Comment: @numzero or `%hs`.

Comment: @numzero %S did work, could you make it as an answer? Also please could you link me "the docs"?

Comment: Do not use `wsprintf`. Microsoft documentation [says so](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-wsprintfa). Try `swprintf` instead.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I would even advice to move away from that too and use std::stringstream instead.

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: Yes, i'm using windows.

Comment: [`wsprintf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-wsprintfw) is a Microsoft Windows function. You should use `swprintf` or (preferable to that) the [`swprintf_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwprintf) function, which are both standard. Use `%hs` for any of those. However, since you are using C++, you should consider using [`wstringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) (in `<sstream>`) or (if you have C++20 support) `std::format` (in [`<format>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/format)).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm `swprintf_s` isn't standard in C++. It's standard, but optionally provided in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for if you need to convert between string and wstring.
It seems conversion between those strings is a "hard" problem.
The C++ standard library had support for it, but it will be removed.
So I fall back to a windows API call here.

```
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <Windows.h>

// just use std::string when you mean text. Not const char*
// to avoid conversion between character sets you could use std::wstring here too
static std::map<int, const std::string > wmTranslation = 
{ 
    {0, "WM_NULL" },
    {1, "WM_CREATE" },
    {2, "WM_DESTROY" },
};

std::wstring convert(const std::string& s)
{
    std::array<wchar_t, 256> buffer;
    auto result = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, s.c_str(), -1, buffer.data(), static_cast<int>(buffer.size() * sizeof(wchar_t)));
    if (result < 0) throw std::runtime_error("input string could not be converted");
    return std::wstring{ buffer.begin(), buffer.end() };
}

void Msg(int Msg) 
{
    std::wstringstream s;

    const auto& translatedMessage = wmTranslation[Msg];
    auto wide_string = convert(translatedMessage);
    //wsprintf(wsText, L"Msg: %s", wide_string);
    s << L"Msg: " << wide_string;

    std::wcout << s.str() << std::endl;
    ::OutputDebugString(s.str().c_str());

}

int main()
{
    Msg(WM_CREATE);
    return 0;
}
```